# understanding parameters passed to -v in Docker

Tags: docker

If i run the below command in my terminal,

```
$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
```

I kind of understand how the -v command works now, but i am still not quite understanding the above command quite well, i am essentially having a difficulty understanding how,

```
-v /dbdata
```

works , what is that part of the command really doing ? I really fail to understand what `-v /dbdata` is really doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-v /dbdata` allocates a [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) and makes it available at `/dbdata` inside the container.  A Docker "volume" is a chunk of storage allocated by the docker storage engine that is distinct from the rest of your container filesystem.

Quoting from the documentation:

> ### Data volumes
>
> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more
>   containers that bypasses the Union File System. Data volumes provide
>   several useful features for persistent or shared data:
>
> Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point,
>   that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume
>   initialization.
>
> - Data volumes can be shared and reused among containers.
> - Changes to a data volume are made directly.
> - Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image.
> - Data volumes persist even if the container itself is deleted.
>
> Data volumes are designed to persist data, independent of the
>   container’s life cycle. Docker therefore never automatically delete
>   volumes when you remove a container, nor will it “garbage collect”
>   volumes that are no longer referenced by a container.